# trying to use json_decode but it keeps returning a string instad of a object

Tags: php

I'm trying to access the information in a JSON string by using json_decode,
but it is returning a string instead of a object. My code

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));           // print json object to make sure it is working
$obj = json_decode($json);              // get json object
print $obj->{'time'}; // 12345          // error because obj is a string
```

Comment: If `$json` is actually a JSON string (i.e. `"text-in-double-quotes"`), `json_decode` will return a string. You'll have to provide an example of the string `$json` contains to help people help you.

Comment: Try to validate your JSON string (https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: You need to (a) read the instructions on how to format code in questions and (b) provide a [mcve]

Comment: What's the output `var_dump($json)`? Most likely it's not a JSON-formatted string.

Comment: @Keloo true , so true.   But `"a_quoted_string"` is valid :)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yes, the output is a string, but the input? Like your sarcasm xD

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this below one instead of $obj = json_decode($json)

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

Ex:

```
$obj = '{"name":"vijay","age":27,"city":"New York"}';
$obj = json_decode($obj,true);
echo $obj["name"];  // vijay
```

Comment: shooting spaghetti at the wall to see if it sticks ?

Comment: This won't solve the issue. It's not returning as an stdClass, it's returning as a string; meaning the input is a string->json not an array->json.